# RegExp Match PHP

Tags: php, regex, match, regex-group

Data:

```
N15319542045C13_1_3/61488007C13-130083_1_3/61488007C13-130083-1_1_3/P1197443641_1_3SD|1
NP1196939393_1_3SU|OD=2/7;|BNP1196939393_1_3SU|OD=2/7;|BNP1196930222_1_3SU|OD=4/11;|
NP1196930222_1_3SU|OD=4/11;|
N15319384625C13_1_3/61445794C13-130077_1_3SD||BN15319384625C13_1_3/61445794C13-130077_1_3SD||
```

RegExp:

```
(N(.*?)S([UID])\|(.*?))(?:B|\|.?$)
```

I am trying to find 7 matches using above regex but only 6 are matching. Not sure how to fix to match 1st line as well.

Format:

```
N(key)S(action)|(value or end)
```

end depend on different matches

I solved it if someone else needs:

```
(\x15(.*?)\x01([UID])\|(.*?))(?:.*?\x08|.*\|?$)
```

Comment: (\x15(.*?)\x01([UID])\|(.*?))(?:.*?\x08|.*\|?$)

Answer (score 1):

The regex didn't work because after the `S[UID]` you expect 2 `|` as per the regex but in the first input string there is only one.

One fix is to make the second group optional and move out the string end anchor `$`

```
(N(.*?)S([UID])\|(.*?))(?:B|\|.?)?$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fjoxrn/1)**

---

Or may be more simpler as

```
N.*?S[UID]\|.*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fjoxrn/2)**

Comment: If you are just looking for `N` followed by `S` followed by the action, you can make it very simpler. Take a look at the edit I have added. Hope it helps

Comment: sorry, my data is not ending at B, I edited my question and data to match. Now its return 6 match but its should return 7

Comment: Can multiple NS* can occure at the same line?

Comment: yes, think of I am extracting commands from data. some times multiple command are on same line.

Comment: In that case we cant use `$` as the line doesnt end with the pattern that we are looking for. Also in that case the we need more description to identify how each of these data end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133311/discussion-between-wasim-a-and-nu11p01n73r).